# Error Message: TF401320 - Having trouble creating a feature using the Azure CLI with Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-cli

Greeting,

I'm having issues creating a feature using the Azure CLI commands with Python. I have tried running the command manually in the virtual studios terminal and receive the same error message, but when I change the work item to 'User Story' it works fine. Am I missing something?

Error Messages:

```
TF401320: Rule Error for field Capabilities. Error code: Required, HasValues, LimitedToValues, AllowsOldValue, InvalidEmpty.
```

My Code:

```
import subprocess
import requests
from datetime import date 

organization = "https://dev.azure.com/Company_name"
project = "Project_name"
area = '"Area\path\xxx\xxx\"'
iteration = "Iteration_name"
planning_interval = "interval_path"

type = '"User Story"'
title = "Testing"
description = '"Testing by Norway the Linux Man"'

feature = 'Feature'
feature_title = '"Testing Feature"'
year = date.today()
prior = '"Priority=1"'
#Setting the iteration path for the work item
iteration_path = f'"{project}\{year.year}\{planning_interval}\{planning_interval} {iteration}"'
iteration_path_feat = f'"{project}\{year.year}\{planning_interval}"'
#print(iteration_path)
#print(iteration_path_feat)

# Create a feature in Azure using Azure CLI and link it to a story

create_feature_command = f"az boards work-item create --title {feature_title} --type {feature} --org {organization} --project {project} --iteration {iteration_path_feat} --area {area} --fields -f {prior} "
#create_story_command = f"az boards work-item create --title {title} --type {type} --description {description} --org {organization} --project {project} --iteration {iteration_path} --area {area}"

create_feature = subprocess.run(create_feature_command, shell=True, text=True) 
#create_story = subprocess.run(create_story_command, shell=True, text=True)
```

I have commented out the lines that arent impportant in this question.

```
import subprocess
import requests
from datetime import date

organization = "https://dev.azure.com/Company_name"
project = "Project_name"
area = '"Area\path\xxx\xxx\"'
iteration = "Iteration_name"
planning_interval = "interval_path"

feature = 'Feature'
feature_title = '"Testing Feature"'
year = date.today()
#prior = '"Priority=1"

iteration_path_feat = f'"{project}\{year.year}\{planning_interval}"'

create_feature_command = f"az boards work-item create --title {feature_title} --type {feature} --org {organization} --project {project} --iteration {iteration_path_feat} --area {area} "


create_feature = subprocess.run(create_feature_command, shell=True, text=True)
```

Error Messages:

```
TF401320: Rule Error for field Capabilities. Error code: Required, HasValues, LimitedToValues, AllowsOldValue, InvalidEmpty.
```